# Basic Authentication appears to have no security header

Tags: c#, wcf, fiddler, basic-authentication

I have written a very simple WFCSerice that returns the Windows username supplied.  Here is the client side code:

```
public Form1()
        {
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client s1 = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            s1.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            string str = s1.ReturnWindowsUsername();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

I can see the credentials in the HTTP Header using Fidddler:

[image]

I have tried to do the same thing with Basic Authentication (accessing another web service that supports Basic Authentication).  Here is the client side code:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client s1 = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            s1.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "testuser";
            s1.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "testpassword";
            string str = s1.GetData(1);

        }
```

Here is the screenshot from Fiddler when using Basic Authentication:

[image]

Why is there nothing in the header when using Basic Authentication.  The Basic Authentication service seems to work as expected.  Here is the response (interestingly there appear to be two requests and two responses):

[image]

Comment: Do you have anonymous authentication disabled, and basic authentication enabled in IIS? The Authorization header is only added to the request *after* a 401 challenge from the server. If the request is allowed anonymously, there is no 401 and hence no need for the header.

Comment: @user1429080, both are enabled.

Comment: Try disabling the anonymous authentication. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @user1429080, If I do this then the following exception is thrown: System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: Additional information: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm=mydomain.mypc.local.

Comment: How does the "trace" of the request look in Fiddler? There should be a 401 response from the server, then a new request with the header added from the client. If you get a 404 then the username/password combination is invalid.

Comment: @user1429080, I have edited the question with the response.

Comment: Could this have anything to do with the binding e.g. The security header is hidden with an encrypted channel I.e. Https?

Comment: @user1429080, do you have any other suggestions? Basic Authentication is working as expected, however there is no security header in Fiddler.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic authentication works on the `HTTP` level. The general flow is that the client requests a resource, then the server issues a challenge, then the client issues a new request with an `Authorization` header included. If the username and password in the `Authorization` header are accepted by the server, the client will usually then add the header for subsequent request without going through the `request - challenge - re-request-with-authorization` steps again.

If you have everything setup correctly, you should expect to see two requests in Fiddler.

1. One request with no `Authorization` header included. The response from the server for this request will be a `401` with a `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="your realm"` header attached.
2. Then you should see a second request where an `Authorization` header has been sent from the client.

Here is a sample from my environment:

[image]

If you don't see the `401` challenge from the server, then basic authentication is not correctly set up.

In order for the service proxy to supply the header, you need to configure your client binding to use `<transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>`. Or that's what I did, who knows with WCF with it's myriad of configuration options.

**EDIT**: I used this on the service side:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="httpTransportCredentialOnlyBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

On the client:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:53156/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="WcfTest_CBT.IService1"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```

I use `basicHttpBinding`, `TransportCredentialOnly` and `Basic` in order to test this easily without SSL hassle etc.

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried what you suggested.  Still no Security in the header.  Basic authentication is working as I would expect however, I have absolutely no idea whatsoever how the credentials are passed to the server.

Comment: No I don't.  Does it have to be a BasicHttpBinding for the credentials to be passed in the header? My research is telling me that credentials are passed in the SOAP message (encrypted) with wsHttpBinding.  I am quite new to this.

Comment: What binding do use use? What is the security mode?

Comment: Thanks again.  I have these settings and now I cannot update my service reference.  It says: "The server needs to authenticate your request.   Your credentials will be sent in clear text.  Do you want to continue?" Any ideas?

Comment: thanks.  It is not accepting my basic auth credentials.  It just keeps prompting me for them.

Comment: I have a UserNamePasswordValidator on the server side.  Does that make a difference?

Comment: sorry I cannot access the chat page.  I think it is blocked by my corporate firewall for some reason.

Comment: Where is the reference to the  UserNamePasswordValidator in your web.config?

Comment: When having IIS configured to use basic authentication, you must use a local computer accont and password, or a domain account. The authentication is performed by IIS before your service gets a chance to do anything... Btw let's clean up the comments a but...

Comment: is the validator ever actually reached?

Comment: I have asked another question about this here this morning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42200995/iis-basic-authentication-constantly-prompted-for-user-details.  Could you take a look? I think I am nearly there.  I am just trying to prove to myself how this works.

Comment: I have got this proof of concept working.  Thanks for your help.