# Does ClientCredentials.UserName mean basic authentication?

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, soap

Please see the code in the linked webpage: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.clientcredentials.username(v=vs.110).aspx and the example code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client s1 = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            s1.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "TestUser";
            s1.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "TestPassword";
            string str = s1.GetData(1);

        }
    }
```

If I want to use Windows authentication then I use: `s1.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;`

If you supply the username and password using: ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName and ClientCredentials.UserName.Password respectively, then does the client always communicate with the Basic Authentication?

This question follows from this question: [Basic Authentication appears to have no security header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42067363/basic-authentication-appears-to-have-no-security-header).  I am confused why I do not see basic authentication credentials in the Authorisation header.

I have read the documentation here, but I have not found the answer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.clientcredentials.username(v=vs.110).aspx.